# Implementing 2FA with Asp.Net Core Identity Core For a Single Page Application

Tags: c#, single-page-application, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to implement 2FA for a SPA using Asp.Net Core Identity. However I got stuck.

Complete code for the `Authenticate2fa` method can be found at the end of the description.

In the code, the line below always has null value for `user`. I reckon there is some magic happening in `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()`, however I was not able to find where the magic is even I refer to the source code.

```
var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
```

Thus `await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(authenticatorCode, false, false);` just doesn't work.

There is offical document around how to implement 2FA for MVC however I am not able to find anything related to SPA.

Am I on the right track or what am I missing?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("authenticate2fa")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate2fa([FromBody]LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var loginResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginModel.Username, loginModel.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (!loginResult.Succeeded && !loginResult.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return BadRequest("user-password-error");
            }

            var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
            if(user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("unable-to-load-2fa-user");
            }

            var authenticatorCode = loginModel.TwoFactorCode.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);
            var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(authenticatorCode, false, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok(await GenerateAuthenticatedUser(user));
            }
            else if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return BadRequest("account-locked");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("invalid-2fa-code");
            }
        }

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

I just use the following method directly to verify the two factor token.

```
UserManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(...)
```

Since SignInManager relies on `HttpContext`, it uses the `IAuthenticationService` providers to handle the 2FA request, and you need to look at what are the providers (for `IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme`) for `IAuthenticationHandlerProvider`. In my case, the `TwoFactorUserIdScheme` is handled by `CookieAuthenticationHandler`.

While it's JWT token, no doubt it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way. If you want to write your own two-factor authentication, but you're stuck because you can't get past TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync() (because it always returns Fail), you can just log them straight in. So in the LoginWith2fa.chhtml, you 1) verify that they entered the 2fa code that you sent them via text/email, 2) and then you force-log them in like this:

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, null);
```

This just forces them to be signed in. I've used this code when building admin functions so that our administrators can view anyone in the system without knowing their password. It's extremely powerful.

If you don't do this, you will be forced to override iUserValidator() and iClaimsTransformation() and register stuff in Startup. That's too much work and is unnecessary.